# Scroll back to the section

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with scrolling to the top of the page. I have a page with different sections. In the third and the last section of the page. I have this HTML:

```
<section class="recipes-overview">
<h1><strong>23</strong> Recepten</h1>

<ul class="recipes-list">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>

<a href="j#" title="Laad andere recepten" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_btNext">Laad volgende recepten</a>
</section>
```

When you click on the a href button. Then, three li items. When you press it again. Are there three more li items.

But now come the problem. When I click on the a button. The data is coming from the backend. The page is refreshing.

But, refreshing the page yourself and you're back at the top of the page.

You need to refresh will go to this section. How can I make that?

Comment: Can you give a code of your button? Is it inside of the form or something?

Comment: so when you click the `<a>` the data is loaded dynamicly and now you want to go to this section when refreshing the page?

Answer (score 0):

Use *html*

```
  <p><a name="top"></a></p>
  <p>...</p>
  <p><a href="#top">Top</a></p>
```

Or use *jQUery*

```
.scrollTop()
```

http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/